# iOS app project modularisation with cocoa pod

Tags: ios, design-patterns, architecture, mobile-development

I would like to know the pros and cons of following app architecture.

The app will have 5 features: login, feature1, feature2, feature3, and feature4. Refer to the attached UI.

To modularise the features in this application, each feature will be developed as a separate cocoa pod project. The main app will pod these features as libraries. The main app will do the necessary linking, navigation, etc. Refer to the attached architecture.

[image]
[image]